# How to know if the user didn't input something after a minute in C

Tags: c, scanf

The project I'm working on - Mine sweeper game- requires that when the user stays idle and don't input something for a whole minute the time be updated. That's exactly how the professor said it "When the user is idle for a minute, update the time."
so how can I know that the scanf didn't return anything for a minute so that i can take a certain action. Because to my understanding the scanf function has to scan something for it to proceed to the next line.

Answer (score 1):

Here With 2 more options you can do it :-

1. Poll() Function (probably the most 'correct' way on Linux)

```
#include <poll.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>    
int main()
{
    struct pollfd mypoll = { STDIN_FILENO, POLLIN|POLLPRI };
    char string[10];

    if( poll(&mypoll, 1, 10000) )
    {
        scanf("%9s", string);
        printf("Read string - %s\n", string);
    }
    else
    {
        puts("Read nothing");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The timeout is the third argument to poll and is in milliseconds - this example will wait for 10 seconds for input on stdin. Windows has WSAPoll, which should work similarly.

2. Try Alarm()

This is another method to solve you problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(void)
{
     char buf [10];
     alarm(10);
     scanf("%s", buf);
     return 0;          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Terminals in cannonical mode are line buffered. You'll need to switch the terminal to raw mode so that your app can see the keystrokes as they're entered, and then you can use synchronous read functions such as read/scanf in combination with a signal based timer or a function like select.

E.g. (based on the example from https://linux.die.net/man/2/select):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    fd_set rfds;
    struct timeval tv;
    int retval;

    struct termios oldt, newt;


    //switch terminal to raw mode
    tcgetattr( STDIN_FILENO, &oldt);
    newt = oldt;
    newt.c_lflag &= ~( ICANON | ECHO );
    tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt);

    /* Watch stdin (fd 0) to see when it has input. */
    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_SET(0, &rfds);

    /* Wait up to two seconds. */
    tv.tv_sec = 2;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    retval = select(1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
    /* Don't rely on the value of tv now! */

    if (retval == -1)
        perror("select()");
    else if (retval)
        printf("Data is available now.\n");
    /* FD_ISSET(0, &rfds) will be true. */
    else
        printf("No data within two seconds.\n");

    tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt);
    return 0;
}
```